# How to use 'Electron-forge package' without copy source code?

Tags: electron, electron-forge

When I use `electron-forge package`，it create a dir '/out', like below:

`out/
- appname-forge-win32-x64/
- - locales/
- - resources/
- - - app/
- - - electron.asar`
 
In dir app are my source code。It is sure that I can run .exe without them.
How to configure electron-forge, that I can package without copying source code?

Answer (score 5):

add this in package.json

```
"build": {
"asar": true,
}
```

after packaging, it will convert your source code into .asar file

```
out/
- appname-forge-win32-x64/
- - locales/
- - resources/
- - - app.asar
- - - electron.asar
```

Comment: I am using version electron-forge 6.x and I had to add the `"asar":true` in `packagerConfig` object instead of putting it in root path in package.json. just FYI.

Comment: maybe you use different version

Comment: Yes but asar file is still there and still contains all the source code. Though if i remove "asar" option it fails complaining on path length.